# Trading signals example from Marginal Revolution blog

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, independence

From http://marginalrevolution.com/marginalrevolution/2016/09/someone-give-doug-blog.html:

> Many trading signals reliably predict prices, but not strongly enough
>   to overcome transaction costs (i.e. exchange fees, clearing fees,
>   liquidity costs, etc.). A stock can moves up or down .01 in the next
>   period, your trading signals predicts the right direction 60% of the
>   time, and transaction costs average .0025. Unfortunately after costs,
>   you'll end up losing $.0005 per trade, so it's not a viable strategy.
>
> But let's say you’ve got **three uncorrelated trading signals** just like
>   it. **If you wait until all three point in the same direction, now
>   there’s a 94% of the stock moving in your favor.** You easily clear the
>   transaction cost threshold and neatly make .0063 per trade. When you
>   gather together multiple uncorrelated signals, the whole becomes worth
>   much more than the sum of the parts.

Is the math for the three-signal example correct?  Isn’t $$\Pr\left[ X = 1 | S_1=1, S_2=1, S_3=1 \right] = \frac{0.5 \cdot 0.6^3}{0.5\cdot0.6^3 + 0.5\cdot0.4^3} \approx 0.771$$ and not 0.94?

Let $X = 1$ if the stock moves up, $-1$ if it moves down, and assume these each occur with 0.50 probability. Conditional on $X$, each signal has 0.6 probability of agreeing with $X$, and 0.4 probability of disagreeing. We’re assuming the three signals are conditionally independent given $X$.

Is my math wrong?  Am I misunderstanding the setup?  Or is there a mistake in the blog post I cited?

It's not clear to me exactly what the post means by "uncorrelated signals."  I assume they mean uncorrelated conditional on $X$.

Toy R simulation:

```
get_df <- function(n_obs=10^5, pr_match=0.6) {
    ## Signals match x with probability pr_match, and are independent conditional on x
    x <- sample(c(-1, 1), size=n_obs, replace=TRUE)
    x_opposite <- ifelse(x == 1, -1, 1)
    s1 <- ifelse(runif(n_obs) < pr_match, x, x_opposite)
    s2 <- ifelse(runif(n_obs) < pr_match, x, x_opposite)
    s3 <- ifelse(runif(n_obs) < pr_match, x, x_opposite)
    return(data.frame(x=x, s1=s1, s2=s2, s3=s3, x_opposite=x_opposite))
}

df <- get_df(n_obs=10^6)

mean(df$x == 1)  # Roughly 0.5
with(subset(df, x == 1), mean(s1 == 1))  # Roughly 0.6
with(subset(df, s1 == 1), mean(x == 1))  # Roughly 0.6
with(subset(df, s2 == 1), mean(x == 1))  # Roughly 0.6
with(subset(df, s3 == 1), mean(x == 1))  # Roughly 0.6
with(subset(df, s1 == 1 & s2 == 1 & s3 == 1), mean(x == 1))  # Roughly 0.769

(0.5 * 0.6^3) / (0.5*0.6^3 + 0.5*0.4^3)  # Pr[X = 1 | S1=1, S2=1, S3=1]
```

I think a "94% [probability] of the stock moving in your favor" would require seven signals with each $S_i = 1$, not three.

Comment: I think it's likely they just (erroneously) reasoned that $1 -  0.4^3 = 0.936 \approx 0.94$.

Comment: @cardinal good point -- that's a very plausible explanation.